# Error 1215 MySQL Cannot add foreign key constraint”

Tags: mysql

no consigo solucionar este error que me sucede al intentar crear una base de datos en MySQL Workbench, y es que, tengo varias tablas en las cuales en dos tablas tengo 'Foreign Keys', pero en una sí me funcionan y en la otra tabla no y me da el error 1215... He intentado cambiar las constraint pero no encuentro el fallo.

Os comparto el código por si me podéis echar una mano, he intentado de todo.

```
        DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS ELECTIENDA;
    CREATE DATABASE ELECTIENDA;

    /*DROP TABLE IF EXISTS TIENDA;
    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS ELECTROS;
    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS CLIENTES;
    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS PRECIOS;
    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS VENDEDOR;
    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS VENTAS; */

    USE ELECTIENDA;

    CREATE TABLE TIENDA
        ( CODTIENDA SMALLINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY CHECK (CODTIENDA>999), CHECK (CODTIENDA<10000),
          NOMTIENDA CHAR(100) NOT NULL,
          DIREC_TIENDA CHAR(100) NOT NULL,
          TLF_TIENDA VARCHAR(9) NOT NULL )
    engine = innoDB ;
      
    CREATE TABLE ELECTROS 
        ( CODELECT CHAR(9) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
          DESCRIPCION VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL )
    engine = innoDB ;

    CREATE TABLE CLIENTES
        ( COD_CLI INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
          NOM_CLI VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
          DOMICILIO_CLI VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
          TLF_CLI CHAR(9) NOT NULL )
    engine = innoDB ;

    CREATE TABLE PRECIOS
        ( CODELECT CHAR(9) NOT NULL,
          CODTIENDA SMALLINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
          PRECIO_UNIDAD DECIMAL(8,2) NOT NULL,
      
      CONSTRAINT FK_PRECIOS_ELECTROS
      FOREIGN KEY (CODELECT) 
      REFERENCES ELECTROS(CODELECT),
      
      CONSTRAINT FK_PRECIOS_TIENDA
      FOREIGN KEY (CODTIENDA) REFERENCES TIENDA(CODTIENDA) )
      
      /* PRIMARY KEY ( CODELECT, CODTIENDA),
      CONSTRAINT FK_PRECIOS_ELECTROS
      FOREIGN KEY (CODELECT)
      REFERENCES ELECTROS(CODELECT),
      CONSTRAINT_FK_PRECIOS_TIENDA
      FOREIGN KEY (COTIENDA) */
    engine = innoDB ;

    CREATE TABLE VENDEDOR
        ( NIF_VDDOR CHAR(9) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
          NOMBRE_VDDOR CHAR(100) NOT NULL,
          TLF_VDDOR CHAR(9) NOT NULL )
    engine = innoDB ;

    CREATE TABLE VENTAS
        ( CODELECT CHAR(9),
          CODTIENDA SMALLINT UNSIGNED,
          COD_CLI TINYINT,
          FECHAHORA_VENTA TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
          UNIDADES_VENDIDAS TINYINT NOT NULL,
          DESCUENTO FLOAT(2) NOT NULL,
          NIF_VDDOR CHAR(9) NOT NULL,
      
 

 PRIMARY KEY (CODELECT, CODTIENDA, COD_CLI, FECHAHORA_VENTA),
      
      
  

CONSTRAINT FK_COD_ELECT
    FOREIGN KEY (CODELECT) 
        REFERENCES ELECTROS(CODELECT) 
        ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE CASCADE,
      
  

    CONSTRAINT FK_COD_TIENDA
        FOREIGN KEY (CODTIENDA) 
            REFERENCES TIENDA(CODTIENDA)
            ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE CASCADE,
      
      CONSTRAINT FK_COD_CLIENTE
        FOREIGN KEY (COD_CLI) 
            REFERENCES CLIENTES(COD_CLI)
            ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE CASCADE,
      
      CONSTRAINT FK_NIF_VENDEDOR
        FOREIGN KEY(NIF_VDDOR) 
            REFERENCES VENDEDOR(NIF_VDDOR)
            ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    
    CONSTRAINT FK_VENTAS_PRECIOS
        FOREIGN KEY (CODELECT, CODTIENDA)
            REFERENCES PRECIOS(CODELECT, CODTIENDA)
            ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE CASCADE )
            
engine = innoDB ;
```

¿Alguien que pueda echarme una mano por favor? Uso ubuntu 18.04 con MySQL WorkBench, y aunque intento bucar soluciones y llevo así unos días, no consigo encontrar el fallo. Gracias.

Comment: Para poder crear claves foreanes, una de las condiciones es que las columnas tienen que ser indices en la tabla referenciada. Sin buscar mucho una clave que veo mal es `FK_VENTAS_PRECIOS`. [Mas info](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html#foreign-key-restrictions)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Par de cosas:

1. Tienen que tener el mismo tipo. No puede ser SMALLINT en una tabla y luego INT UNSIGNED en otra.
2. Una FK jala una PRIMARY KEY de otra tabla. Esa FK `FK_VENTAS_PRECIOS` no funciona por eso (no hay PK en PRECIOS).

El script corregido anda así:

```
CREATE TABLE TIENDA
        ( CODTIENDA SMALLINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY CHECK (CODTIENDA>999), CHECK (CODTIENDA<10000),
          NOMTIENDA CHAR(100) NOT NULL,
          DIREC_TIENDA CHAR(100) NOT NULL,
          TLF_TIENDA VARCHAR(9) NOT NULL )
    engine = innoDB ;
      
    CREATE TABLE ELECTROS 
        ( CODELECT CHAR(9) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
          DESCRIPCION VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL )
    engine = innoDB ;


    CREATE TABLE CLIENTES
        ( COD_CLI INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
          NOM_CLI VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
          DOMICILIO_CLI VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
          TLF_CLI CHAR(9) NOT NULL )
    engine = innoDB ;

    CREATE TABLE PRECIOS
        ( CODELECT CHAR(9) NOT NULL,
          CODTIENDA SMALLINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
          PRECIO_UNIDAD DECIMAL(8,2) NOT NULL,
      
      CONSTRAINT FK_PRECIOS_ELECTROS
      FOREIGN KEY (CODELECT) 
      REFERENCES ELECTROS(CODELECT),
      
      CONSTRAINT FK_PRECIOS_TIENDA
      FOREIGN KEY (CODTIENDA) REFERENCES TIENDA(CODTIENDA) )
      
      /* PRIMARY KEY ( CODELECT, CODTIENDA),
      CONSTRAINT FK_PRECIOS_ELECTROS
      FOREIGN KEY (CODELECT)
      REFERENCES ELECTROS(CODELECT),
      CONSTRAINT_FK_PRECIOS_TIENDA
      FOREIGN KEY (COTIENDA) */
    engine = innoDB ;




    CREATE TABLE VENDEDOR
        ( NIF_VDDOR CHAR(9) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
          NOMBRE_VDDOR CHAR(100) NOT NULL,
          TLF_VDDOR CHAR(9) NOT NULL )
    engine = innoDB ;





    CREATE TABLE VENTAS
        ( CODELECT CHAR(9) NOT NULL,
          CODTIENDA SMALLINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
          COD_CLI INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
          FECHAHORA_VENTA TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
          UNIDADES_VENDIDAS TINYINT NOT NULL,
          DESCUENTO FLOAT(2) NOT NULL,
          NIF_VDDOR CHAR(9) NOT NULL,
      
         PRIMARY KEY (CODELECT, CODTIENDA, COD_CLI, FECHAHORA_VENTA),

         CONSTRAINT FK_COD_ELECT
        FOREIGN KEY (CODELECT) 
        REFERENCES ELECTROS(CODELECT) 
        ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE CASCADE,
         
         
         
        CONSTRAINT FK_COD_TIENDA
        FOREIGN KEY (CODTIENDA) 
            REFERENCES TIENDA(CODTIENDA)
            ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE CASCADE,
         
         CONSTRAINT FK_COD_CLIENTE
        FOREIGN KEY (COD_CLI) 
            REFERENCES CLIENTES(COD_CLI)
            ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE CASCADE,
        
      
        CONSTRAINT FK_NIF_VENDEDOR
        FOREIGN KEY(NIF_VDDOR) 
            REFERENCES VENDEDOR(NIF_VDDOR)
            ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE CASCADE
        )
        
          
engine = innoDB ;
```

Para añadirle ese último FK a VENTAS, tendrías que crear una PK compuesta en PRECIOS:

```
CREATE TABLE PRECIOS
        ( CODELECT CHAR(9) NOT NULL,
          CODTIENDA SMALLINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
          PRECIO_UNIDAD DECIMAL(8,2) NOT NULL,
      
      CONSTRAINT PK_PRECIOS PRIMARY KEY (CODELECT, CODTIENDA),
      CONSTRAINT FK_PRECIOS_ELECTROS
      FOREIGN KEY (CODELECT) 
      REFERENCES ELECTROS(CODELECT),
      
      CONSTRAINT FK_PRECIOS_TIENDA
      FOREIGN KEY (CODTIENDA) REFERENCES TIENDA(CODTIENDA) )
      
    engine = innoDB ;

-- ...
-- Y, En la tabla VENTAS: 
-- ...

CONSTRAINT FK_VENTAS_PRECIOS
        FOREIGN KEY (CODELECT, CODTIENDA)
            REFERENCES PRECIOS(CODELECT, CODTIENDA)
            ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE CASCADE
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu ayuda, pude solucionarlo, eres un grande.

Comment: @Soullesito me alegra poder ayudar :)